# How can I override destroy_if_previously_invited in devise_invitable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using `devise_invitable` with `devise` in my Rails 3 app.  I want to give my users the ability to invite other users and group those invited users in advance of the invitees signing up.

My problem is that once the invitee comes along and signs up (but doesn't use the invite URL), the `destroy_if_previously_invited` around_filter comes along, destroys the original user record and recreates a new record for the user, retaining the invitation data but not transferring the user_groups records along with it.

I'd like to simply override this around_filter by doing a search for any user_groups that match the originally invited user_id and saving them with the newly created user_id.

I keep getting the error:

```
LocalJumpError in Users::RegistrationsController#create

no block given (yield)
```

My route looks like this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }
```

I've set this as the override in app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  around_filter :destroy_if_previously_invited, :only => :create


  private    

  def destroy_if_previously_invited
    invitation_info = {}

    user_hash = params[:user]
    if user_hash && user_hash[:email]
      @user = User.find_by_email_and_encrypted_password(user_hash[:email], '')
      if @user
        invitation_info[:invitation_sent_at] = @user[:invitation_sent_at]
        invitation_info[:invited_by_id] = @user[:invited_by_id]
        invitation_info[:invited_by_type] = @user[:invited_by_type]
        invitation_info[:user_id] = @user[:id]
        @user.destroy
      end
    end

    # execute the action (create)
    yield
    # Note that the after_filter is executed at THIS position !

    # Restore info about the last invitation (for later reference)
    # Reset the invitation_info only, if invited_by_id is still nil at this stage:
    @user = User.find_by_email_and_invited_by_id(user_hash[:email], nil)
    if @user
      @user[:invitation_sent_at] = invitation_info[:invitation_sent_at]
      @user[:invited_by_id] = invitation_info[:invited_by_id]
      @user[:invited_by_type] = invitation_info[:invited_by_type]
      user_groups = UserGroup.find_all_by_user_id(invitation_info[:user_id])
      for user_group in user_groups do
        user_group.user_id = @user.id
        user_group.save!
      end
      @user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

I may also just be going about this all wrong.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no need to set the around_filter again, as devise_invitable already sets this. All you need to do is redefine the methods in your UsersController and those will be called instead of the devise_invitable ones.

Second, it looks like you are combining the two methods when they should remain seperate and overridden (I am basing this off latest version of devise_invitatable 1.1.1)

Try something like this:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def destroy_if_previously_invited
    hash = params[resource_name]
    if hash && hash[:email]
      resource = resource_class.where(:email => hash[:email], :encrypted_password => '').first
      if resource
        @old_id = resource.id #saving the old id for use in reset_invitation_info
        @invitation_info = Hash[resource.invitation_fields.map {|field|
          [field, resource.send(field)]
        }]
        resource.destroy
      end
    end
  end

  def reset_invitation_info
    # Restore info about the last invitation (for later reference)
    # Reset the invitation_info only, if invited_by_id is still nil at this stage:
    resource = resource_class.where(:email => params[resource_name][:email], :invited_by_id => nil).first
    if resource && @invitation_info
      resource.invitation_fields.each do |field|
        resource.send("#{field}=", @invitation_info[field])
      end
      ### Adding your code here
      if @old_id
        user_groups = UserGroup.find_all_by_user_id(@old_id)
        for user_group in user_groups do
          user_group.user_id = resource.id
          user_group.save!
        end
      end
      ### End of your code
      resource.save!
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you - that really helped!  Upgrading to the most recent version of `devise_invitable` seemed to be key here.